# Count the number of data frames beginning with prefix in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a collection of data frames that I have generated in R. I need to count the number of data frames whose names begin with "entry_". I'd like to generate a number to then use for a function that rbinds all of these data frames and these data frames only.

So far, I have tried using grep to identify the data frames, however, this just returns where they are indexed in my object list (e.g., 16:19 --- objects 16-19 begin with "entry_"):

```
count_entry <- (grep("entry_", objects()))
```

Eventually I would like to rbind all of these data frames like so:

```
list.make <-  function() { 
     sapply(paste('entry_', seq(1:25), sep=''), get, environment(), simplify = FALSE) 
}

all.entries <- list.make()
final.data <- rbind.fill(all.entries)
```

I don't want to have to enter the sequence manually every time (for example (1:25) in the code above), which is why I'm hoping to be able to automatically count the data frames beginning with "entry_".

If anyone has any ideas of how to solve this, or how to go about this in a better way, I'm all ears!

Comment: You could try `mylist <- mget(ls(pattern = "^entry_"))` to create a list of the corresponding objects. Afterwards, you could rbind them and to remove the originals from the global environment you can use, quite similar: `rm(ls(pattern = "^entry_"))` (take care - if you run this, they'll be gone).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't familiar with mget. This works quite well for my purposes, and with half the code.

Answer (score 0):

Per comment by docendo: The `ls` function will list objects in an environment that match a regex pattern. You can then use `mget` to retrieve those objects as a list:

```
mylist <- mget(ls(pattern = "^entry_"))
```

That will then work with `rbind.fill`. You can then remove the original objects using something similar: `rm(ls(pattern = "^entry_"))`